# Calculating my grade with curve equation given?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I received a $\frac {43}{70}$ on an exam and my professor gave us the following curve equation to calculate our adjusted grade, I was wondering how I calculate it?

Here is the curve equation: $2+\frac {1*(x-40)}{12}$

Thanks!

Comment: What does $x$ represent?

Comment: i wish i knew, but the professor didn't really say anything...im not sure if it's my final raw score or the percent

Answer (score 1):

You plug in 43 for $x$ to get
$$
g = 2 + \frac{1*(43 - 40)}{12} = 2 + \frac{3}{12} = 2 + \frac{1}{4} = 2.25.
$$

Comment: is 2.25 what i add onto my grade? or what is 2.25's significance?

Comment: We don't know. That's something you ask your instructor.

Comment: By the way, both the "2" and the "1 *" seem very unlikely to me. When you need to multiply something by 1, you usually just omit the multiplication, for instance. Was there perhaps a transcription error?